# Display full name of apps shown in iTunes sync page

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization

As shown in the image, is it possible to see the full name of the app ? For instance, Adobe Reader is shown as 'Adobe Rea...' .

[image: itunes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag the entire window wider, or fullscreen it, but there's a limit to how wide it will go. There appears to be no separate column resize facility.

Narrowest...

[image]

Widest...

[image]

Comment: Oh strangely, the App column got widened a little when I did a minimize > maximize of the iTunes window. Thanks for the tip which led me to try this out :)

Comment: Welcome. Glad you got it :)